# Php online examination #confusee

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, html

I am working on a project that has to do with urrrh An online examination and I was in the middle of the project and I got confused

Here it goes

I want the questions loaded out of the database which I already did,

I created a column in the database with the name question_number

So with that column I will have to insert 50 questions I.e 1-50

After inserting the questions I will have to fetch them out, I do and I fetched them out on a buttons I.e

Here is where I'm confused

All the questions are out and all the buttons are working

> how will I echo first question from the database to be the first question on the page
>
> when number two question is clicked from the button I want it to show on the same page
>
> After that when all those are set and after the questions and options are out

When the user chooses an option or answers a specific question  and clicks on another question number and it loads, how will I store the question answered until the user clicks final submit all button and it will submit all the answered question

Here is the code I'm working with.

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM year2011 WHERE subject_cat = 'English' AND question_number = '1' ORDER BY question_number ASC"; 
$result = $con->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
$rows = $result->num_rows; 
while($res = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?> 
    <h4><?php echo $res["question_text"]; ?></h4>
    <p> <label><input type="radio" id="english_option" name="english_option" value="<?= $res['option_a']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $res['option_a']; ?></label><br/> 
    <label><input type="radio" id="english_option2" name="english_option" value="<?= $res['option_b']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $res['option_b']; ?></label><br/> 
    <label><input type="radio" id="english_option3" name="english_option" value="<?= $res['option_c']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $res['option_c']; ?></label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" id="english_option4" name="english_option" value="<?= $res['option_d']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $res['option_d']; ?></label><br/> </p>
    <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM year2011 WHERE subject_cat = 'English' ORDER BY question_number ASC"; 
    $result = $con->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
    $rows = $result->num_rows; 
    while($res = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        if($res['question_number'] == 1) { ?> 
            <button class='btn btn-group'><?=$res['question_number']; ?></button> <?php
        }else { ?> 
            <button class='btn btn-group btn-success'><?=$res['question_number']; ?></button><?php 
        } 
     } 
endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide some code for what you have tried. Will help to understand whats going on. If you want the first question you might need ORDER BY mysql clause, again code will help.

Comment: <?php 
                            
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM year2011 WHERE subject_cat = 'English' AND question_number = '1' ORDER BY question_number ASC";
                        
                            $result = $con->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                            
                            $rows = $result->num_rows;                                 while($res = $result->fetch_assoc()):
                            ?>
                            <h4><?php echo $res["question_text"]; ?></h4>

Comment: <p>
                                <label><input  type="radio" id="english_option" name="english_option" value="<?= $res['option_a']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $res['option_a']; ?></label><br/>
                                <label><input type="radio" id="english_option2" name="english_option" value="<?= $res['option_b']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $res['option_b']; ?></label><br/>
                                <label><input type="radio" id="english_option3" name="english_option" value="<?= $res['option_c']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $res['option_c']; ?></label><br/>

Comment: <label><input type="radio" id="english_option4" name="english_option" value="<?= $res['option_d']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $res['option_d']; ?></label><br/>
                            </p>

Comment: <?php
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM year2011 WHERE subject_cat = 'English' ORDER BY question_number ASC"; $result = $con->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                            
                            $rows = $result->num_rows; while($res = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                if($res['question_number'] == 1) {
                            ?>
                                <button class='btn btn-group'><?=$res['question_number']; ?></button>
                            <?php

Comment: }else {
                            ?>
                                <button class='btn btn-group btn-success'><?=$res['question_number']; ?></button><?php
                                    }
                            }
                            endwhile;?>

Comment: Thats what i've been working on Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look and and this part doesn't look right

```
<?=$res['question_number']; ?>
```

which is in your if statement. Should be

```
<?php echo $res['question_number']; ?>
```

same problem for your else statement and radio buttons.
Also in your if statement, you will need to run the intval() function to convert from string to int.
`intval($res['question_number'])`

This code should do the trick.

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM year2011 WHERE subject_cat = 'English' AND question_number = '1' ORDER BY question_number ASC"; 
$result = $con->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
$rows = $result->num_rows; 
while($res = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?> 
<h4><?php echo $res["question_text"]; ?></h4>
<p> <label><input type="radio" id="english_option" name="english_option" value="<?php echo $res['option_a']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $res['option_a']; ?></label><br/> 
<label><input type="radio" id="english_option2" name="english_option" value="<?php echo $res['option_b']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $res['option_b']; ?></label><br/> 
<label><input type="radio" id="english_option3" name="english_option" value="<?php echo $res['option_c']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $res['option_c']; ?></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" id="english_option4" name="english_option" value="<?php echo $res['option_d']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $res['option_d']; ?></label><br/> </p>
<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM year2011 WHERE subject_cat = 'English' ORDER BY question_number ASC"; 
$result = $con->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
$rows = $result->num_rows; 
while($res = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
    if(intval($res['question_number']) == 1) { ?> 
        <button class='btn btn-group'><?php echo $res['question_number']; ?></button> <?php
    }else { ?> 
        <button class='btn btn-group btn-success'><?php echo $res['question_number']; ?></button><?php 
    } 
 } 
endwhile;?>
```

Rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: Thanks Web Dev Guy after trying the new code there is still an itch with the  project , after the questions and buttons are out with the options , the user will have to pick an answer and go to the next question by pressing  the question number two button ,( not with next and previous) so it'll load the next question and remove the previous question with ajax , how will I know if a user choose number one question and store it, number two question and store it, and so on, then at the end of the question it should submit all the questions answered

Comment: `<?= … ?>` is a perfectly valid alternate syntax for `<? echo … ?>`.

Comment: @duskwuff Thanks did not know that, but looks like server needs to be configured to use it.

Comment: @ayomidegabriel Have you got any javascript code which you have tried?

Comment: @Web Dev Guy ,  I don't know how to go with the JavaScript

Comment: Try something like hiding the other inputs with css, `display: none;` then add `onclick="showInput2()"` and`id="input2"` to your html input. then have a js function `function showInput2() {document.getElementById("input2").style.display = "block";}`
Sorry this is a quick solution, about to go out.

Comment: @WebDevGuy The `<?=` syntax is always enabled, and has been since PHP 5.4.